# Reading first row using ODBC text driver

Tags: c#, odbc

I have an application that reads a delimited file using ODBC. The connection string is as follows:

```
cs = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DBQ=" + sPath1;
```

One of the companies providing a file is not using a header row, and I'm losing the first row of data. Putting `HDR=No` in the connection string does not seem to help. There is a `schema.ini` in the target directory.

```
cs = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};HDR=No;DBQ=" + sPath1;
```

What's the best way to read the first row? I haven't tried the Excel driver because I'm afraid it will interpret data differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to be sure there is a line reading

```
ColNameHeader=False
```

in the schema.ini. Documentation can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the correct answer, you can also write a function to create/write your schema file as a `FileStream` at run time. Include `ColNameHeader=False` (or pass it as a parameter) when you write to the file.  The file name must be `schema.ini`

```cs
private void writeSchema(string decimalPointOverride = "", string header="True")
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream( myDirectory + "\\schema.ini", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter srOutput = new StreamWriter(fsOutput);
        string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6;

        s1 = "[" + "OutputFileName.CSV" + "]";
        s2 = "ColNameHeader=" + header;  
        s3 = "Format=" + this.strFormat;
        s4 = "MaxScanRows=25";
        s5 = "CharacterSet=" + this.strEncoding;
        //set decimal point if exists, otherwise put empty string ""
        s6 = (decimalPointOverride == "") ? "" : "DecimalSymbol=" + decimalPointOverride + "\r\n";

        srOutput.WriteLine(s1.ToString() + "\r\n" + s2.ToString() + "\r\n" + s3.ToString() + "\r\n" + s4.ToString() + "\r\n" + s5.ToString() + "\r\n" + s6.ToString());
        srOutput.Close();
        fsOutput.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "writeSchema");
    }

}
```